# primevue/config does not exist

Tags: primevue

I am using PrimeVue 2.0.0 with a Vue 2 application. The documentation mentions the following:

```
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
Vue.use(PrimeVue);
```

However, primevue/config does not seem to exist. I cannot find it anywhere within the node module itself. Does anyone know if this step is deprecated/the file has been renamed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeVue 2.0.0 doesn't have primevue/config, [more details](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/975)
The config api was introduced in 2.3.0. I also recommend to use PrimeVue 3.*